# Which parts of the pandas source code are responsible for it to be used in a jupyter notebook?

Tags: pandas, jupyter

I was reading about pandas and got to know that it was not written specifically for jupyter notebooks but how it was built makes it easy to be imported in a notebook environment and be used.
I was curious to know which part of the pandas source code does this work of notebook integration

I know that pandas is a python package and packages can be imported, but is there something else in the source code responsible for it's seamless notebook integration?

Comment: So you know, a lot of packages pre-date Jupyter Notebooks. The traditional way to run Python is to make `.py` scripts and run them on the command line using Python. I cannot speak to all the ways Pandas has added to deal with Jupyter, but one of the big ones is common to packages that add special features to customize representations of output in Jupyter is setting `_repr_mimebundle_` to define how to represent the objects. For example, this is how you get special display of dataframes inside Jupyter where it uses html and css to make the dataframe look like a fancy table and not just text ...

Comment: <continued> that you'd get in the Python console/interpreter if you printed a dataframe. See [here on the page about 'Integrating your objects with IPython'](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/integrating.html#MyObject._repr_mimebundle_) for more about  `_repr_mimebundle_`. Jupyter inherits a lot from IPython because Jupyter developed out of the IPython Notebook project when it added the ability to use other language kernels. The IPython Notebook project was the predecessor of Jupyter and developed out of IPython. See an example of using `_repr_mimebundle_` to customize things ...

Comment: <continued> [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-to-write-a-class-which-naturally-produce-a-latex-output-in-jupyter-notebook/17437/3?u=fomightez).